# PHP replace background-image url

Tags: php, css, replace

I want to receive all background-image url links with ability to change them. For example modify only local links.

```
from this css:
#img1 { background-image: url('http://someurl.com/someimg.png'); }
#img2 { background-image: url('images/bg2.jpg'); }


to this css:
#img1 { background-image: url('http://someurl.com/someimg.png'); }
#img2 { background-image: url('somefolder/images/bg2.jpg'); } /* <- modified */
```

Currently I'm able only to replace all url, not checking is it local:

```
$css = file_get_contents($file);
$css = str_replace('url("', 'url("'.$stringToAdd, $css);
file_put_contents($file, $css);

// not used
function isexternal($url) {
  $components = parse_url($url);    
  return !empty($components['host']) && strcasecmp($components['host'], 'example.com');
}
```

Comment: you are right it must have http:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` function:

```
$css = file_get_contents($file);
echo $css;
preg_match_all("/background-image: url\('(.*)'/", $css, $arr);
$images = $arr[1];
```